# mlq5 create a gui and have button to manage my trade

Tags: mql5

I would like to know how to create a GUI with buttons that can manage my trades faster, for example close 50% of the trade when I click a button. I've been looking all over the mql5 forums and everything and there is 0 info. This makes me really angry and my last resort is stackoverflow. I have 0 experience with metaeditor & mlq5 programming.
If someone can provide me any lead to a GUI with buttons where I can code the buttons or even somewhere where there is info to create it myself I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In every install of MetaTrader 5, if you look in the "Navigator" window, under "Expert Advisors" you will see a group called "Examples". In this group is a sub-group called "Controls" and within this is a fully editable Expert Advisor which gives an example of how to add Controls to your EA's (buttons, check boxes, selection boxes, lists, dates, etc.).